# Can a character command a PC-possessed animal

Tags: dnd-5e, homebrew, barbarian

One of the PCs was given a chance to possess his wardog, rather than creating a new character after dying.

Can another character command the wardog, like an animal, such as with a Handle Animal check? Is there something about the PC's soul that causes it to be treated like a human?

Comment: If this is home brew a lot more detail will be required. Also you've listed dnd-5e but then mentioned Will saves, which are not a thing in fifth edition.

Comment: Corrections made. I'm old and have 4 versions in my head to sort thru.

Comment: How did the wardog come to be possessed by the player's mind and soul?

Comment: I have submitted an edit. If it passes, please confirm that I captured the essence of the question.

Answer (score 5):

A dog PC is going to break a lot of game rules most likely but I guess the best option is to use the druid **Wild Shape** rules to govern his behavior. It most closely matches the idea of a mind and soul controlling an animal body.

Following those rules, he has total control of himself as he did when he was a humanoid. As an aside, even if you wanted to use a different rule set, making a PC have to save to disobey orders every time would remove a lot of the player's agency, which is generally frowned upon.